# ArcGIS Server folder registration

Tags: arcgis-server

I'm new to ArcGIS Server. I've installed both ArcGIS Server 10.2 and Desktop (10.2) on a virtual machine with Windows Server 2019. I've installed Web Adaptor and enabled Microsoft IIS service too. Now when I want to register a folder on ArcGIS Server, I get "invalid folder location. Unable to access this location". I've tried all possible ways to solve the problem, but nothing has been changed.
My machine name is Server. My data is located on C:\Data folder. The folder has full control (Read and Write) permission for ArcGIS Server account, Everyone and Administrator users. I've tried different path type such as C:\Data, \server\data for publisher and server data path.

Comment: That's very old software for such a new operating system. Normally this would be a question for Tech Support, but support for 10.2 ended two summers ago. Look in the logs to see if there's more info there.  Note that 10.2.2 was a significant improvement over 10.2, so if you're using 10.2.0, there's literally no one else using that software anymore.

Comment: Thanks Dear Vince for your comment. I have the same problem with ArcGIS Server 10.5. The Publisher and server are on the same machine. Could it make the problem??